# How to use AsNoTracking in a service layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, domain-driven-design, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I usually use AsNoTracking when I'm not intending to write anything. How should I handle this in my service layer where dbContext is hidden behind it? (I treat EF core as repository because it is repository)

```
public class SomeService
{
    //...

    public SomeEntity GetById(int id)
    {
        return _dbContext.Find(id);
    }

    public SomeEntity GetReadonlyById(int id)
    {
        return _dbContext.SomeEntitities.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
    }

    public SomeEntity Update(SomeEntity someEntity)
    {
        _dbContext.Update(someEntity);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public class SomeController
{
    private readonly SomeService _someService;

    //....

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        var someEntity = _someService.GetReadonlyById(id);
        if (someEntity == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return someEntity;
    }

    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Modify(int id, SomeEntity modified)
    {
        var someEntity = _someService.GetById(id);
        if (someEntity == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        someEntity.Someproperty = modified.Someproperty;
        _someService.Update(someEntity);
        return Ok(someEntity);
    }
}
```

Is there any better way to do this?

I can also define my service as follows:

```
public class SomeService
{
    //...

    public SomeEntity GetById(int id)
    {
        return _dbContext.AsNoTracking.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
    }

    public SomeEntity Update(int id, SomeEntity someEntity)
    {
        var entity = _dbContext.SomeEntities.Find(id);
        if (entity == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        entity.Someproperty = someEntity.Someproperty;
        _dbContext.Update(entity);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return entity;
    }
}

public class SomeController
{
    private readonly SomeService _someService;

    //....

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        var someEntity = _someService.GetById(id);
        if (someEntity == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return someEntity;
    }

    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Modify(int id, SomeEntity modified)
    {
        var someEntity = _someService.Update(id, modified);
        if (someEntity == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(someEntity);
    }
}
```

What is the better way?

Comment: I would prefer the second approach. if we have to talk about Segregation of concern desing, then Repository should only know how to fetch and how to update the data from context instead of external layer.

Comment: @user1672994 I think you're right. I don't need to care how to update it from my controller because service does it for me and implementation details are hidden.

Comment: It is pretty confusing to me because everyone does it differently and mostly there's no AsNoTracking in the implementation or just nobody cares about this feature.

Comment: There's no usage of it even here https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers and there is no any official recommendation on how to approach this

Comment: Somehow your SomeService  _is_ a Repository. With all the complications and drawbacks.

Comment: @bommelding Yeah it's basically a CRUD, but think about this way, if you have generic service then it's easier to extend than having generic repository

Comment: It is still useful sometimes to have logic separated and keeping controllers lean

Comment: What if just drop your `SomeService` and use context directly? I mean with current implementation it doesn't add anything useful to it.

Comment: @Evk I'd like to have some generic CRUD interface that I can extend(to eliminate boilerplate), because some entities can have some custom logic and it's harder to extend/override controller actions because they return action results and not entities/dtos.

Comment: Imagine that I have some abstract CRUD controller that implements basic actions, actions mostly return `IActionResult` or `ActionResult<T>` in case of 2.1 when wanting to override some logic in my derived controller it looks kinda messy because I usually have to retrieve the result somehow. In case of services I get that result directly which seem like a better fit for extensible approach. So theoretically I should extend my business layer and not my presentation layer(controllers).

Comment: That CRUD interface could ideally follow *Interface Segregation Principle* so you can choose if specific entities can use C/R/U/D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it is more common problem.

It is often happens that optimized reading methods are not convenient for updating scenarios and convenient reading methods for updating scenarios have unnecessary overhead for reading only scenarios. I see 3 options here:

1. Ignoring all problems with performance and just use universal `GetById` from your first approach for reads and updates. Obviously, it is applicable for simple applications and may not be applicable for high-load applications.
2. Using [CQRS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/cqrs). It means you will have completely separate data model for reads and updates. Since reads usually don't require the complex domain logic it allows you to use any optimizations like `AsNoTracking` method or even use a plain `sql` in repositories. It is applicable for complex apps and requires more code.
3. Trying to find some compromise between these two options according to your particular needs.

As noted in comments your `SomeService` looks like repository. Ideally, domain service should contain only business logic and shouldn't mix it with infrastructure features like `AsNoTracking`. Whereas repositories can and should contain infrastructure features like `AsNoTracking`, `Include` and etc.

Comment: Can't I just make all methods accepting the id and use `AsNoTracking` where appropriate instead of expecting an instance?

Comment: For example `Update(int id, Entity entitytoupdate)` instead of `Update(Entity entitytoupdate)`

Comment: It is common that some services look like repositories, but with DTO mapping on top of it, so they're pretty much like CRUD services but they return and accept DTOs instead of domain models

Comment: Why not. It is like you did in the your second approach. It can be applied to the third option in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

No tracking queries are useful when the results are used in a read-only scenario. They are quicker to execute because there is no need to setup change tracking information.

You can swap an individual query to be no-tracking:

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blogs = context.Blogs
        .AsNoTracking()
        .ToList();
}
```

You can also change the default tracking behavior at the context instance level:

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;

    var blogs = context.Blogs.ToList();
}
```

Ideally, you should manage the infrastructure stuff in the repository level.

Comment: This turns off tracking on an entire context as opposed to the expected scope:  only one query.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution. It works.

**BASE CLASS OF ALL SERVICES**

```
public class ServicesBase
            {
                protected AppDbContext dbcontext { get; }
      
                public ServicesBase(AppDbContext dbcontext)
                {
                    this.dbcontext = dbcontext;      
                }
        
                public void AsNoTracking()
                {
                    dbcontext.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
                }
        
                public void SaveChanges()
                {
                    dbcontext.SaveChanges();
                }
        
            }
```

**USING IN CONTROLLER**

```
_masterService.AsNoTracking();
var master = _masterService.GetById(1);
master.WagePerSquareMeter = 21;
_masterService.SaveChanges(); 

//or dbcontext.SaveChanges(), both of them will ot affect the database.
```

Comment: Already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57483441/861716). Please don't repeat answers.

Comment: @GertArnold I've used it with base class and it contains different and more useful way to solve the issue. Please think twice before unlike an answer, so it may be helpful for someone.

Comment: The main idea is to use `dbcontext.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior`. Personal varieties can go on forever, giving later users more content to wade through. Think twice before adding an answer. It's probably more helpful to keep a Q&A concise. Side note: it doesn't even answer the *exact* question: EF's `AsNoTracking()` changes only one query. Your `AsNoTracking()` permanently changes a context. That's unexpected behavior.